# Why my cast is not valid?

Tags: c#, xml

I am using a routine to read data from Xml files similar to this:

```
<VerificationSample X1 = "1" X3 = "3" ../>
```

using this call:

```
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(path);
reader.ReadToFollowing("VerificationSample");

this.X1 = (double)FileStructure.GetAttributeSafe(reader, "X1", typeof(double)); // exists
this.X2 = (double)FileStructure.GetAttributeSafe(reader, "X2", typeof(double)); // doesn't exist
```

However, some attributes might not exist so I handle it using this routine inside that attribute reader function definition:

```
public static object GetAttributeSafe(XmlReader reader, string attributeName, Type objectType)
{
    // ..
    string value = reader.GetAttribute(attributeName);

    if (value != null) // attribute exists
    {
        if (objectType != typeof (string))
        {
            var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(objectType);
            returnValue = converter.ConvertFrom(value);
        }

        else // is already a string and doesn't need to be converted
        {
            return value;
        }
    }
    else // attribute doesn't exist
    {
        return "0";
    }
}
```

If the attribute doesn't exist, application pops an error:

> Specified cast is not valid

What is my mistake?

Comment: If the attribute does not exist then your method returns the *`string`* `"0"`.  This cannot be cast to `double`.

Comment: @john but if the reader read `"0"` from the file, which is a string. It works. And if I do this `value = "0"; return value;` it also doesn't work. Why?

Comment: When you read a "0" from the file you go to some trouble to convert it to the requested type.  You do not exercise that code path when the requested attribute is not present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the attribute doesn't exist, you `return "0"`, which you are then trying to cast to a double.  You need to return a default value of whatever `objectType` is, perhaps by doing

```
else // attribute doesn't exist
{
    if(objectType.IsValueType)
    {
        return Activator.CreateInstance(objectType);
    }
    return null;
}
```

You will only return null if you try to convert to something non-immutable like a class instead of an int or string, which will blow up your function anyway; it's just there so all code paths return something.

Comment: but I don't want to `return null` in any case right? So where should I put your piece of code? Also if you could explain to me why if the reader read `"0"` from the file, which is a string, it works fine

Comment: I just changed my `return "0";` to your `return Activator.CreateInstance(objectType);` Thanks

Comment: If you read `"0"` from the file, it gets converted by the `converter`; if you `return "0"`, it does not.

Comment: Also, you might want to look into converting this function to use generics.  `this.X1 = FileStructure.GetAttributeSafe<double>(reader, "X1");` reads a lot better than `this.X1 = (double)FileStructure.GetAttributeSafe(reader, "X1", typeof(double));`

Comment: Then I need to change my reader to discard parameter `typeof(double))`?

Answer (score 3):

Because you are returning "0" , which is a String, and you can't Cast this to double. Use Convert.toDouble(String s) instead.

Comment: I see. It's a confusion because it read `"0"`s just fine from the files. Your solution worked. Thanks. But what if it's not a double? I need to make it generic